# Is it possible to change the Azure VM OS for Azure VMs where the OS is included in the pricing? (Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, virtual-machines

I have an Azure VM that was created with the OS included in the price. Is it possible to upgrade the same VM to a newer OS (e.g. one that would also be included in the VM price)?

Specifically, I would like to upgrade from Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter to Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

If it is possible, how do you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK upgrading Windows isn't supported in Azure; you're meant to start a new VM and migrate your workload to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An in-place system upgrade is not supported on Windows-based Azure VMs, below is a link to the officially statement and some options if you REALLY need to go that route.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014997/an-in-place-system-upgrade-is-not-supported-on-windows-based-azure-vms

Answer (score 2):

No, Aside from upgrades not being supported, there is really not much reason to upgrade an Azure VM since you can simply build a new one and install your app (probably) far faster than an upgrade would take.

Comment: Maybe _you_ can. We are installing a 3rd-party app that also needs a bunch of other ancillary software installed and additional configuration. It takes about 2 days to set everything up. Besides, if you had a modern .NET web app (without a bunch of legacy ActiveX cruft) it would make more sense to just use Azure PaaS instead of messing around with VMs. :-)

Comment: @user228546 understood, take a look at using DSC or ARM templates to deploy your software and configs to cut down deployment time.

Answer (score -2):

I did manage to upgrade in-place some of my Azure VMs, summarized it here for future reference:
https://www.mattiasdesmet.be/2020/04/26/upgrade-the-azure-vm-windows-os/